# How to use SleepEx with alertable true AND an overall minimum sleep time?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, sleep

I have the following use case: My current thread needs to do `operation1`, waits some amount of time to coordinate with others and afterwards needs to do 
`operation2`. In between the waiting, APCs might need to be processed by that thread because of file system events, which add another `operation1` to some queue to be processed later after `operation2` is finished by the current thread. Something simple like the following:

```
while (true)
{
  processOperation1;
  SleepEx(..., true);
  processOperation2;
}
```

The important thing is that between `operation1` and `operation2` at least the specified amount of time to `SleepEx` has to be elapsed! That doesn't need to be in one piece, the thread can instantly be used to process APCs and queue another `operation1`, it just shouldn't continue with `operation2` unless the specified amount of time has elapsed.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If the parameter is TRUE and the thread that called this function is the same thread that called the extended I/O function (ReadFileEx or WriteFileEx), the function returns when either the time-out period has elapsed or when an I/O completion callback function occurs. If an I/O completion callback occurs, the I/O completion function is called. If an APC is queued to the thread (QueueUserAPC), the function returns when either the timer-out period has elapsed or when the APC function is called.

From my understanding that means that if `SleepEx` is called and an APC has been queued, that is directly executed by the current thread because it is capable to do so. But what happens afterwards with the code after `SleepEx`? Does the thread return to process `operation2` because `SleepEx` returned control or does the thread gets back to sleep, staying in `SleepEx` until the specified amount of time is elapsed?

The first sentence in the docs is not speaking about returning from the function, but "resuming the thread":

> Suspends the current thread until the specified condition is met. Execution resumes when one of the following occurs:

That could mean that the thread is resumed, processes APCs and afterwards stays in `SleepEx`, sleeping for whatever amount of time is needed.

If that's not the case and `SleepEx` is really left, does it tell how much time has elapsed? `SleepEx` doesn't seem to provide that value, but only some constant return value. This sounds like I would need to take time before and after `SleepEx` on my own and call that function again and again in a loop until the time I need really has elapsed? Is there already something out there like that, maybe as part of `boost`?

Thanks!

Comment: It is just not a sensible requirement.  If you want to minimize the latency then don't make it alterable.  Having worker threads handle the I/O completions is standard today with IOCP, boost::asio uses it too.

Comment: if *apc* executed during `SleepEx` - after *apc* `SleepEx` just return control. for example `SleepEx(INFINITE, TRUE)` - return after *apc*

Comment: @HansPassant I don't want to minimize latency, but really want to mainly wait in the situation I'm asking for and wondered how to deal with APCs in an environment using those. With the current answer one could simply use SleepEx instead of Sleep always and doesn't need to care if APCs are used or not.

Comment: Typically, you do need to care whether APCs are being used, because it might not be safe to perform an alertable wait if they are.  In particular, you're likely to have trouble if the function performing the wait is being called from within an APC.  From what you've said in the question I don't think this is a problem for you, but I thought I should mention it just in case.

Comment: PS: depending on your circumstances, it *might* be more elegant for processOperation1() and processOperation2() to be APCs themselves, with processOperation2() called via a [waitable timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686898(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @HarryJohnston The "only" problem one might get in your scenario is if APCs are queued so often that former SleepEx-calls never return control to the caller to actually finish processing, correct?

Comment: You mean, the alertable wait inside an APC?  No, I don't think that's too likely, though if it did happen you'd crash once you exhausted the available stack space due to the excessive recursion.  The more likely problem is functions being called recursively that aren't designed for it, with consequences ranging from none to severe depending on the code in question.

Comment: Alternatively, in the NT API you can delay until an absolute system time via `NtDelayExecution(BOOLEAN Alertable, PLARGE_INTEGER Interval)`, which works like [`KeDelayExecutionThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551986) without the `WaitMode` parameter. The current system time can be queried using  `NtQuerySystemTime(PLARGE_INTEGER SystemTime)`, to which the delay can be added in 100 ns units. `SleepEx` delays with a relative (i.e. negative) interval instead of an absolute time, and it rewaits from the beginning for `STATUS_ALERTED`, i.e. `NtAlertThread` (rarely called).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `SleepEx` in a loop and process the queued APCs until the needed timeout elapses.

Something like this.

```
for (DWORD dwStart = GetTickCount(); ; )
{
    DWORD dwElapsed = GetTickCount() - dwStart;
    DWORD dw = (dwTimeout > dwElapsed) ? (dwTimeout - dwElapsed) : 0;
    if (!SleepEx(dw, TRUE))
        break;
}
```