# How many APCs are processed during SleepEx?

Tags: windows, multithreading, sleep

This is somewhat related to a [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220843/how-to-use-sleepex-with-alertable-true-and-an-overall-minimum-sleep-time) of mine about how `SleepEx` actually works. [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686307(v=vs.85).aspx) say that the thread executing `SleepEx` is resumed whenever APC is queued and APC might keep being queued while the thread already executes APC.

So how long does the thread keeps executing APCs? Is it until the queue is empty whenever checked and in that moment `SleepEx` returns control to the caller? Or is only exactly one APC executed by that thread, then `SleepEx` returns and another execution of APC would need `SleepEx` to be called one more time?

I have the feeling that APCs are executed until the queue is empty for the first time. Thanks!

Comment: It is unknowable.  The thread that calls QueueUserApc() has no idea whether the alertable thread has resumed.  Whether or not the alertable thread works down the queue before resuming just doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant My question is not from the perspective of QueueUserApc, but how SleepEx works.

Comment: @HansPassant - you mistake. this is probably undocumented, but exaclty known - when thread return from *APC* - system check are additional APC inserted in thread. and if yes - execute it. so this will be in loop, until no more APC in thread

Comment: Hmya, I did not say yes or no, I said it doesn't matter.  Anybody that thinks it matters is almost guaranteed to be nursing a threading race bug that they cannot fix.

Comment: Just recognized that: "How many" was used in the question because it was short only and "1" might have been a valid answer, even "15" might have been hard-coded somewhere. I didn't care about an actual number to rely on and the question body makes that pretty clear in my opinion. Asking for "How long..." in the subject as well doesn't mean I want to know seconds or minutes or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APCs are executed until the queue is empty. when your code returned from APC - system check are another APCs inserted - if yes - next *APC* is execute, until no more APC inserted in thread. after this `SleepEx` (or any another alertable wait api) return control to you

---

the APC executed in next way - when you call certain api (`SleepEx`, `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`, `WaitForSingleObjectEx`, `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` .. with the function's bAlertable parameter set to TRUE) kernel check are APC inserted in thread object. if yes - kernel copy the user mode thread context to it stack, than change thread context (user mode return address set to `ntdll.KiUserApcDispatcher`) and return. as result code return not from place from where he enter to kernel (in case `SleepEx` this is `ZwDelayExecution` which called internally) but to the `KiUserApcDispatcher`. this api execute *APC* and then call `ZwContinue`. this api declared as:

```
NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS NTAPI ZwContinue(PCONTEXT Context, BOOLEAN TestAlert);
```

in place Context used saved in stack thread context, for return to the point, from which alertable api was called, and `TestAlert` specifies whether should check for additional apc inserted. if call `ZwContinue` with `TestAlert == FALSE` system will be not more check for APC in thread queue until you yourself not call `SleepEx` or other certain api - so will be exactly 1 APC executed. but in `KiUserApcDispatcher` `TestAlert` hardcoded to `TRUE` - you easy can look this yourself, if understand assembly code (the `KiUserApcDispatcher` is tiny)

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but I think Hans is right too: if your code *depends* on this behaviour, you are very probably doing something wrong.    (There may be edge cases.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - yes, agree. but i simply formal answer to question as is. explain how apc work